# Error when inserting coordinates into array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, polyline, cllocation

> Cannot convert value of type '[Dictionary]' to expected
>   argument type 'UnsafePointer'

Is the error I'm getting when trying to insert coordinates into my array.

Here is my code:

```
var locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

    //Updating location + polylines
    @objc func update()
    {
        Annotationtimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: true, block: { (timerr) in

            let currentLat = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
            let currentLong = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude


            let location = [(currentLat!), (currentLong!)]


            self.locations.append(location) //HERE IS THE ERROR
            print(self.locations)


     //Draw polyline on the map
     let aPolyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: locations, count: locations.count)

     //Adding polyline to mapview
     self.mapView.addOverlay(aPolyLine)


        })
    }
```

I'm trying to insert current location into an array, and when I press a button, I wanna draw polylines from start, through all coordinates.

What am I doing wrong? How can I insert the coordinates correctly? I've read other threads about this, but none of them is actually working. So I'd to create a new one.

Why dislike? At least you can tell me the reason for it.

Comment: Simply replace 'let location = ...' with 'let location =  CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: currentLat!, longitude: currentLong!)' . Your issue is that you were adding an array of CGFloats instead of adding a cllocationcoordinate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentLat` and `currentLong` variables are `String`, and array type is `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

You don't need to extract `currentLat` and `currentLong`, it's better to do like this : `self.locations.append(self.locationManager.location?.coordinate)`

Also, my advice - use `guard` to save app from crashing in situation, where `self.locationManager.location == nil`.

So, here is an example:

`guard let currentLocation = self.locationManager.location else { return } // show error or something else
 self.locations.append(currentLocation)`

Comment: array is of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and `location` property is of type `CLLocation `